# Validation error while tryng to create userpool with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im tryng to create cognito userpool with aws-cli reading a json template

i run this command

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://userpool.json
```

this is the json

```
{
  "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
    "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
    "InviteMessageTemplate": { 
      "EmailMessage": "Caro portador, sua senha temporária para entrar no portal Cateno é {####}    ---    Número da solicitação {username}.",
      "EmailSubject": "Portador: sua senha temporária",
      "SMSMessage": "Portador: Sua senha temporária para entrar no portal Cateno é {####}    ---    Número da solicitação {username}."
   },
    "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7
  },
  "AliasAttributes": [
    "phone_number"
  ],
  "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
    "phone_number"
  ],
  "DeviceConfiguration": {
    "ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice": false,
    "DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt": false
  },
  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "ReplyToEmailAddress": "",
    "SourceArn": ""
  },
  "EmailVerificationMessage": "",
  "EmailVerificationSubject": "",
  "LambdaConfig": {
    "CreateAuthChallenge": "",
    "CustomMessage": "",
    "DefineAuthChallenge": "",
    "PostAuthentication": "",
    "PostConfirmation": "",
    "PreAuthentication": "",
    "PreSignUp": "",
    "PreTokenGeneration": "",
    "UserMigration": "",
    "VerifyAuthChallengeResponse": ""
  },
  "MfaConfiguration": "OFF",
  "Policies": {
    "PasswordPolicy": {
      "MinimumLength": 6,
      "RequireLowercase": true,
      "RequireNumbers": true,
      "RequireSymbols": true,
      "RequireUppercase": true
    }
  },
  "PoolName": "",
  "Schema": [
    {
      "AttributeDataType": "String",
      "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": true,
      "Mutable": true,
      "Name": "",
      "NumberAttributeConstraints": {},
      "Required": true,
      "StringAttributeConstraints": {}
    }
  ],
  "SmsAuthenticationMessage": "",
  "SmsConfiguration": {
    "ExternalId": "",
    "SnsCallerArn": ""
  },
  "SmsVerificationMessage": "",
  "UserPoolAddOns": {
    "AdvancedSecurityMode": "OFF"
  },
  "UserPoolTags": [
    {
      "key": "",
      "value": ""
    }
  ],
  "UsernameAttributes": [
    "email",
    "name"
  ],
  "VerificationMessageTemplate": {
    "DefaultEmailOption": "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE",
    "EmailMessage": "Caro portador, seu código de verificação é {####}",
    "EmailMessageByLink": "",
    "EmailSubject": "Portador: seu código de verificação",
    "EmailSubjectByLink": "",
    "SmsMessage": ""
  }
}
```

but im getting this error

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Invalid template property or properties [UserPoolTags, Policies, VerificationMessageTemplate, MfaConfiguration, Schema, AdminCreateUserConfig, SmsAuthenticationMessage, SmsVerificationMessage, UserPoolAddOns, PoolName, EmailConfiguration, SmsConfiguration, AliasAttributes, EmailVerificationSubject, LambdaConfig, AutoVerifiedAttributes, DeviceConfiguration, EmailVerificationMessage, UsernameAttributes]

what im i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just at a quick glance - I think `PoolName` should be `UserPoolName`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html

Comment: here says poolname https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html

Answer (score 0):

Aws-cli default region was set to sa-east-1 which doesnt support cognito....